# ParseError after adding meta-oe layer Could not inherit file classes/autotools_stage.bbclass?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

UPDATE: The following is are the branches of each layer

```
rama@RR06:~/repositories/poky$ cd meta-qt4/
rama@RR06:~/repositories/poky/meta-qt4$ git checkout pyro
Already on 'pyro'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/pyro'.
rama@RR06:~/repositories/poky/meta-qt4$ cd ..
rama@RR06:~/repositories/poky$ cd meta-virtualization/
rama@RR06:~/repositories/poky/meta-virtualization$ git checkout pyro
Already on 'pyro'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/pyro'.
rama@RR06:~/repositories/poky/meta-virtualization$ cd ..
rama@RR06:~/repositories/poky$ cd oe-meta-go/
rama@RR06:~/repositories/poky/oe-meta-go$ git checkout pyro
error: pathspec 'pyro' did not match any file(s) known to git.
rama@RR06:~/repositories/poky/oe-meta-go$ cd ..
rama@RR06:~/repositories/poky$ cd meta-toradex/
rama@RR06:~/repositories/poky/meta-toradex$ git checkout pyro
M   meta/conf/machine/qemuarm64.conf
Already on 'pyro'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/pyro'.
rama@RR06:~/repositories/poky/meta-toradex$ cd ..
rama@RR06:~/repositories/poky$ cd meta-openembedded/
rama@RR06:~/repositories/poky/meta-openembedded$ git checkout pyro
M   meta/conf/machine/qemuarm64.conf
Already on 'pyro'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/pyro'.
rama@RR06:~/repositories/poky/meta-openembedded$ cd ..
rama@RR06:~/repositories/poky$ cd meta-freescale
rama@RR06:~/repositories/poky/meta-freescale$ git checkout pyro
Already on 'pyro'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/pyro'.
rama@RR06:~/repositories/poky/meta-freescale$
```

I am trying to add a layer called meta virtualization, it is dependent on some layers of meta-openembedded such as meta-oe. One I add these necessary layers I get the following error while bitbaking:

```
NOTE: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-support/vim/vim_7.4.769.bb: base_contains is deprecated, please use bb.utils.contains instead.               | ETA:  0:00:26
NOTE: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-support/vim/vim_7.4.769.bb: base_contains is deprecated, please use bb.utils.contains instead.
NOTE: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-support/vim/vim-tiny_7.4.769.bb: base_contains is deprecated, please use bb.utils.contains instead.
NOTE: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-support/vim/vim-tiny_7.4.769.bb: base_contains is deprecated, please use bb.utils.contains instead.
NOTE: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-support/vim/vim-tiny_7.4.769.bb: base_contains is deprecated, please use bb.utils.contains instead.
NOTE: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-support/vim/vim-tiny_7.4.769.bb: base_contains is deprecated, please use bb.utils.contains instead.
NOTE: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-support/vim/vim_7.4.769.bb: base_contains is deprecated, please use bb.utils.contains instead.
NOTE: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-support/vim/vim_7.4.769.bb: base_contains is deprecated, please use bb.utils.contains instead.
NOTE: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-support/udisks/udisks2_2.1.5.bb: base_contains is deprecated, please use bb.utils.contains instead.          | ETA:  0:00:26
NOTE: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-support/udisks/udisks2_2.1.5.bb: base_contains is deprecated, please use bb.utils.contains instead.
NOTE: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-support/udisks/udisks_1.0.5.bb: base_contains is deprecated, please use bb.utils.contains instead.
NOTE: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-support/udisks/udisks_1.0.5.bb: base_contains is deprecated, please use bb.utils.contains instead.
NOTE: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-support/udisks/udisks2_2.1.5.bb: base_contains is deprecated, please use bb.utils.contains instead.
```

and this:

```
ERROR: ParseError at /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-extended/scsirastools/scsirastools_1.6.4.bb:17: Could not inherit file classes/autotools_stage.bbclass
```

I dont even see the build configuration output. I checked this out and found out that autotools_stage.bbclass had been removed from the file scsirastools_1.6.4.bb in the latest version and said that this can be removed csince not used, I went ahead and did that and got the following errors:

```
NOTE: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-networking/recipes-support/nis/ypbind-mt_1.38.bb: base_contains is deprecated, please use bb.utils.contains instead.
ERROR: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-networking/recipes-support/nis/ypbind-mt_1.38.bb: Error executing a python function in <code>:

The stack trace of python calls that resulted in this exception/failure was:
File: '<code>', lineno: 18, function: <module>
     0014:__anon_35__home_rama_repositories_poky_meta_classes_devshell_bbclass(d)
     0015:__anon_101__home_rama_repositories_poky_meta_classes_sstate_bbclass(d)
     0016:__anon_20__home_rama_repositories_poky_meta_classes_blacklist_bbclass(d)
     0017:__anon_160__home_rama_repositories_poky_meta_classes_siteinfo_bbclass(d)
 *** 0018:__anon_31__home_rama_repositories_poky_meta_openembedded_meta_networking_recipes_support_nis_nis_inc(d)
     0019:__anon_23__home_rama_repositories_poky_meta_classes_systemd_bbclass(d)
     0020:__anon_81__home_rama_repositories_poky_meta_classes_update_rc_d_bbclass(d)
File: '/home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-networking/recipes-support/nis/nis.inc', lineno: 29, function: __anon_31__home_rama_repositories_poky_meta_openembedded_meta_networking_recipes_support_nis_nis_inc
     0025:# so force the package to be skipped here (this will cause a
     0026:# 'nothing provides' error)
     0027:python () {
     0028:    os = bb.data.getVar("TARGET_OS", d, 1)
 *** 0029:    if os == "linux-uclibc":
     0030:        raise bb.parse.SkipPackage("NIS functionality requires rpcsvc/yp.h, uClibC does not provide this")
     0031:}
Exception: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getVar'

NOTE: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-networking/recipes-support/openvpn/openvpn_2.3.7.bb: base_contains is deprecated, please use bb.utils.contains instead.
NOTE: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-networking/recipes-support/nis/ypbind-mt_2.2.bb: base_contains is deprecated, please use bb.utils.contains instead.
ERROR: Failed to parse recipe: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-networking/recipes-support/nis/ypbind-mt_1.38.bb
ERROR: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-networking/recipes-support/nis/yp-tools_2.14.bb: Error executing a python function in <code>:

The stack trace of python calls that resulted in this exception/failure was:
File: '<code>', lineno: 18, function: <module>
     0014:__anon_35__home_rama_repositories_poky_meta_classes_devshell_bbclass(d)
     0015:__anon_101__home_rama_repositories_poky_meta_classes_sstate_bbclass(d)
     0016:__anon_20__home_rama_repositories_poky_meta_classes_blacklist_bbclass(d)
     0017:__anon_160__home_rama_repositories_poky_meta_classes_siteinfo_bbclass(d)
 *** 0018:__anon_31__home_rama_repositories_poky_meta_openembedded_meta_networking_recipes_support_nis_nis_inc(d)
     0019:__anon_23__home_rama_repositories_poky_meta_classes_systemd_bbclass(d)
File: '/home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-networking/recipes-support/nis/nis.inc', lineno: 29, function: __anon_31__home_rama_repositories_poky_meta_openembedded_meta_networking_recipes_support_nis_nis_inc
     0025:# so force the package to be skipped here (this will cause a
     0026:# 'nothing provides' error)
     0027:python () {
     0028:    os = bb.data.getVar("TARGET_OS", d, 1)
 *** 0029:    if os == "linux-uclibc":
     0030:        raise bb.parse.SkipPackage("NIS functionality requires rpcsvc/yp.h, uClibC does not provide this")
     0031:}
Exception: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getVar'

NOTE: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-networking/recipes-support/openvpn/openvpn_2.3.7.bb: base_contains is deprecated, please use bb.utils.contains instead.
NOTE: /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta-openembedded/meta-networking/recipes-support/netcf/netcf_git.bb: base_contains is deprecated, please use bb.utils.contains instead.
```

Is it some other deprecated file calling this old supposedly non-existant file? As I said I just cloned everything recently.
So I put it back again. I just cloned the repos yeaterday, and except for oe-meta-go which is on master, all other branches are on pyro branch.

My setup is poky on pyro branch on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2):

Again, which versions of all your layers are you using? You need to use the corresponding verions / branches in *all* your layers.

The initial warnings `base_contains is deprecated, please use bb.utils.contains instead.` indicates that you have a recent (not too old) bitbake and oe-core.

However, the `scsirastools` did inherit `autotools_stage` in `jethro`; while this line was removed in `krogoth` (relased spring 2016). See [meta-oe/scsirastools_1.6.4.bb](http://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-oe/recipes-extended/scsirastools/scsirastools_1.6.4.bb?h=pyro) to verify that it's not inheriting that class in `pyro`.

For the other error, the is no `openvpn_2.3.7.bb` in `meta-networking` in the `pyro` branch, see [meta-networking / openvpn](http://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-networking/recipes-support/openvpn?h=pyro) to verify that.

In the case of `ypbind-mt`, in the included file `nis.inc`, there's no line:

```
os = bb.data.getVar("TARGET_OS", d, 1)
```

in the `pyro` branch. That line is instead:

```
os = d.getVar("TARGET_OS", True)
```

All of the findings above, tells us that you're mixing branches.

Thus, if you ensure that you have the *same* versions / branches of *all* your layers, you will have a lot less problems.

Mixing versions / branches is *not* supported, and you're left on your own. (I.e. this is only for people who knows what they're doing).

Comment: I get the same error, I went into each of the layers and switched them to pyro.

Comment: No, the `scsirastools` tools recipe in `pyro` doesn't try to inherit `autotools_stage`. So you can't get that error. And for your other error, in `pyro` there's no OpenVPN of version `2.3.7`...

Comment: I am updating the question with the branches of the layers

Comment: I still stand by my comments. There is no openvpn 2.3.7 in meta-networking (pyro) , it's 2.3.9. And scisirastools in meta-oe, doesn't inherit `autools_stage`. You have to verify this again. Just have look at them upstream, and you'll see it.

Comment: Should I just delete the layers and clone new ones from scratch? It seems they are all on pyro I rechecked.

Comment: You should be able to see if they've been modified or not. But sure, it can never hurt to clone them again.

Comment: It able to bitbake (with some other new errors) but it still continues to bitbake, I found meta-mender-core to be the problem. But its on the pyro branch it seems really strange. Without it it continues to bitbake inspite of some errors.